# hsqldb supporting oracle functions like listagg

Tags: hsqldb

I came across few of the challenges while writing testcase's using hsqldb.i tried to test oracle function's like (Wm_concat,Listagg,Decode,over) i am getting error like unexpected token found In my research work i found below statement to support oracle function 
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA  TRUE ; but that did not help I would appreciate if any one help me getting a solution for this Thks

Answer (score 0):

`SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE` only makes HSQL accept Oracle's SQL syntax.  It doesn't supply Oracle functions.

If you want to test things dependent on Oracle functions, you really need to test them in an Oracle database.

Comment: thanks for the reply roby.. looks like using oracle databse is the only option if i don't want to make changes to the queries..